# Python - Getting coordinates without restrictions

Tags: python, geocoding, nominatim, geopy

I'm using Python for getting coordinates (latitude & longitude) for a comprehensive list of cities and postal codes (**thousands of rows, nearing 10 000 rows**).

At the moment I'm using **geopy** and **Nominatim** for downloading the coordinates, but Nominatim has [restrictions](https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/nominatim/) for downloading large datasets.
My script is now constantly failing and I expect it to be because my own dataset of the addresses and postal codes is too large.

Is there a (free?) service, to be used with Python, **that does not have a restriction on how many requests I am allowed to do with it / how many requests per second it allows?** Google Maps or similar maybe?

Comment: You can have your own Geocoder in local with OSM data (as Nominatim), look at the Pelias project : https://github.com/pelias/pelias/

Comment: @J.Monticolo Thank you! Do you know for sure that Pelias won't have restrictions if I try to download 10 000 entries from it in one go? The installation does not seem straightforward so I would like to be sure first that I won't be running into similar problems with it.

Comment: You run it locally with all data on your own machine, so ... no limitation. Pelias is, for simplify, a Nominatim server that you can run locally without limitations (little wrong : the only limitations are your machine hardware).

Comment: Hi, core maintainer of the Pelias geocoder here. I just wanted to clarify the comment by @J.Monticolo.

Pelias and Nominatim are both open source geocoders that you can run on your own hardware. There's little relationship between the projects (although of course we both help each other out from time to time), as they serve different goals. We need both :)

Both projects have hosted versions as well (for Nomatim, the official OSM instance at https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/ui/search.html) and for Pelias there is a commercial instance hosted by [Geocode Earth](https://geocode.earth)

Comment: @orangejulius Thank you for clarifying! If I understood correctly, I would still need a paid lincense for Geocode Earth in order to process thousands of requests per day? Even if I installed Pelias locally on my machine?

Comment: @jeppoo1 No, you can use Pelias without paying anyone. It's a complete and functional open source project released under the MIT license.

Of course I can make a great argument why paying for geocoding through Geocode Earth might save you a lot of time or effort, but it's certainly not required to use Pelias. :)

Comment: @orangejulius Yes, I know that Pelias itself is open source, but I thought requesting is **not** unlimited unless you have a paid license. I have little use for Pelias unless I can make 10 000 requests per day with it. Usually there is a limit of 2500 requests per day in many services. My original question was "Is there a (free?) service, to be used with Python, that does not have a restriction on how many requests I am allowed to do with it / how many requests per second it allows?" and I am still looking for such service.

Comment: @jeppoo1 did you figure out how to use Pelias in python? If so, could you please share with us?

Comment: @qwerty no I didn't unfortunately